# Vim NERD-Commenter: How to uncomment only first level of comments, without uncomment nested comments?

Tags: vim, macvim

I got a problem with NERD-commenter.

If I `<leader>cu` the following code:

```
/*function func(arg) {
    codeish;  // Nested comment.
}*/
```

This is the result:

```
function func(arg) {
    codeish;  Nested comment.
}
```

Note the *2nd line*: The nested comment was *also* uncommented. This is not good.

Perhaps I'm just not using it right. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in the latest version of NERD-Commenter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're the one who has commented out the function, you can avoid it by using `<leader>cc` to comment it out in the first place. In this way, the function will get commented out in a different way, and subsequent `<leader>cu` will work as expected.

If, however, you want to use NERD Commenter to uncomment blocks of code which have been commented out manually (or using a different tool), I don't know how would you go about it. After all, the `cc` and `cu` commands are meant to be reciprocal.

Comment: It's wierd there's no anti-command to `cm` (comment using block delimeters), like `cu` is for `cc` (comment lines individually).